# Diamond problem with four interfaces, no code duplication

Tags: java, inheritance, interface, diamond-problem

What if I have 4 given interfaces A, B, C and D and the inheritance is like this:

- B and C extend A
- D extends B and C

The goal is to implement those interfaces without any code repeating.

I think I understand it's a kind of Diamond Problem, but I don't know how to implement.

I would solve this like this: 
I would write 4 classes like this:

```
class ClassA implements InterfaceA { }
class ClassB extends ClassA implements InterfaceB { }
class ClassC extends ClassA implements InterfaceC { }
class ClassD extends ClassA implements InterfaceD { }
```

Is it useful not extend the implemented Classes PLUS extend the interfaces? 
The interfaces are given by design by contract, and I have to use them.

Comment: What problem are you encountering? Inheriting from an interface twice doesn't cause the problems it does in C++ where there can be conflicting definitions. Interfaces don't have member variables or method definitions so there is no diamond problem.

Comment: You'd need explicit overrides if you're inheriting default methods like ```B.super.someMethod()```

Comment: I would write 4 classes like this:

Class A implements InterfaceA
Class B extends ClassA implements InterfaceB
Class C extends ClassA implements. InterfaceC
Class D extrends ClassA  implements InterfaceD

Is it usefull not extend the implemented Classes PLUS extend the interfaces? 
The Interfaces are given by Design by Contract, and i have to use them.